# C# Google Drive API References

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to connect to `Google Drive` with its API.  Google states that it provides the necessary `DLL`s and references [at this link here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) ("Download the latest version of the library").  However, when I try to add the necessary reference(s), `C#` is unable to find any `DLL`s and a manual search for them yields 0 results.  From the referenced link:

> The ZIP file contains the core library and Drive-specific DLLs.
>   Referencing these DLLs in your solution is discussed in the next
>   section.

The following namespaces need references:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Services;
```

In looking around on the Google link, I don't find anything with the necessary `DLL`s that are referenced in the above.

Note: this is a test desktop console app, not a web application.

**Edit:** I should add, if I add the below files as Existing Items, it still is unable to find most of the assemblies:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.5.0.95-beta.nuspec
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.csproj
packages.config

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Services;
```

Comment: Well, the download file contains the sources only as far as I can see ... You have to recompile them.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the API and it's dependencies via Nuget.org if you want them precompiled. The Nuget version is only slightly out-of-date however, if you want the newest version you will have to download the source and build it.

I'd say go with the Nuget version for simplicity.

[Google Drive API on Nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive/1.2.4737.25317)